# How to force dtype to integer in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I am working with a dataframe that has a column in which all values are None. By default the dtype for this column is object. I need it to be an integer type, likely int64. Why is irrelevant; that's what I need.

I've tried the following:

```
df['field'] = df['field'].astype(int)
```

This does not work. The error is:

> ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer

```
insert_data['data_set_key'] = pd.to_numeric(insert_data['data_set_key'], errors='coerce')
```

This converts the dtype to `float64` which isn't at all what I am lookign for.

ADDENDUM:

The dataframe is being used by SQL Alchemy to populate a table in an Oracle database. That table has an integer field that is not populated at this time. The field in the dataframe is loaded with None which then has a dtype of object. When this data is loaded that seems to be interpreted as a CLOB type and Oracle pukes all over itself. If I change None to 1 it works fine. But that's not an option.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I had not tried, since it just shouldn't work, actually is the answer. Substituting np.NaN for None results in the table being populated with NULL in the desired field.